# Error(Id) returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list

Program where I'm trying to traverse singly linked list, getting error, it seems like do and while loop are not applied properly, please check

The program is below where in i tried to traverse using do while and pointers.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    struct node
    {
        int info;
        struct node *next;
    };
    typedef struct node node;
    node *start, *ptr, *ne;
    ptr=NULL;
    int count=0;
    do
    {
    ne=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("\nEnter Data: ");
    scanf("%d",&ne->info);
    if(ptr!=NULL)
    {
    ptr->next=ne;
    ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    else {
    start=ne;
    ptr=ne;
    }
    printf("\nDo you wish to continue?\n ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
      }while(ch=='y'|| ch=='Y');
      ptr->next=NULL;
      printf("The linked list is: ");
      ptr=start;
      while(ptr!=NULL)
      {
      printf("\t%d",&ptr->info);
      ptr=ptr->next;
      count++;
      }
      printf("\nTotal number of elements: %d",count);
    return(0);     


}
```

Comment: If the linker returns an error (which you didn't copy into the post), your program cannot be run. So the problem isn't with the loop not being "applied".

Comment: When asking about build errors, *always* include the *complete* error output in the question body. Complete, in full, including possible informational notes, without editing, and *as (copy-pasted) text*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
printf("\t%d",&ptr->info);
```

to

```
 printf("\t%d",ptr->info);
```

Also I dont recommend using same name "node" in `typedef struct node node;`
but still it is not an issue.

**EDIT:**

I also found a issue with your code:

Change

```
printf("\nDo you wish to continue?\n ");
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

To

```
printf("\nDo you wish to continue?\n ");
getchar();
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

**Or**

you can also change it to

```
printf("\nDo you wish to continue?\n ");
scanf(" %c",&ch); //add a space before %c
```

**Why this is causing error?**

In a program when you try to print anything using 'printf()' a blank space is left in the buffer so we have to read it and ignore otherwise ch will be assigned with blank space. To read blank space and ignore we have two option as mentioned above. Try any one.

Comment: and even if it working it is not letting me input more than a number, i type a number and it shows the summary

Comment: @AyushShrivastava Check my edit and if it works do give a thumbs up.. :-)